# How to create multiline strings for sql queries that are readable, maintainable and fast?

Tags: java, performance, clean-code, strings

I have some SQL commands that I am trying to figure out the best way to have them in code so that:
1. They are very readable
2. They would be easy to update
3. They won't be performance overhead due to many string construction.

I have something like the following that did not turn out too good.

```
    public class SQLHandler {  
      private static final String CUSTOMER_TABLE = "customer_table";  
      private static final String CUSTOMER_ID = "id";  
      private static final String CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";    
      private static final String CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = "last_name"; 
      private static final String CUSTOMER_TELEPHONE = "customer_telephone";  
      private static final String REP_ID = "customer_representative_id";    


      private static final String REP_TABLE = "representative_table";  
      private static final String REP_ID = "id";  
      private static final String REP_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";    
      private static final String LAST_LAST_NAME = "last_name"; 
      private static final String DEPT_ID = "rep_dep_id";  

      public static ArrayList<Representatives> getRepresentatives(int customerId) {  
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("SELECT")   
       .append(REP_TABLE).append(".").append(REP_ID)  
       .append(",")   
       .append(REP_TABLE)  
       .append(".")   
       .append(REP_FIRST_NAME).append(" FROM")
       .append(CUSTOMER_TABLE).append(" JOIN ").append(REP_TABLE)   
       .append("ON").append(REP_TABLE).append(".")     
       .append(REP_ID).append("=").append(CUSTOMER_TABLE)    
      .append(".").append(REP_ID)  
      .append(" AND")  
      .append(CUSTOMER_TABLE).append(".").append(CUSTOMER_ID)   
      .append("=").append(String.valueOf(customerId));  

    // do query  
    }   
}
```

As you can see none of the (3) are met.
I can't easily update the query and if I saw it again I wouldn't remember exactly what was it.
How can I improve this? (Couldn't format it properly in post)

Comment: Are you really gaining anything by using a string builder/query builder approach instead of sticking the actual query directly into the code?  Also, seems pointless to append "_table" to table names.

Comment: @GrandmasterB:My original idea was that the stringbuilder is more efficient for string concat and by using the constants for the fields I would make it easier to maintain in case of naming changes. But turned out a mess as you can see

Comment: Friends don't let friends use strings for non-string data http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped

Comment: @Jim it's technically more efficient, but unless you are doing hundreds or thousands of them in a short period, the end user won't likely notice any difference.  And by making all the names constants, its making the code unnecessarily complex, imo.  That whole class should really only be about 5 or 6 lines of code.  You have to balance technical efficiency with readability.

Comment: @JaredSmith:But SQL is a string right? What do you mean?

Comment: @Jim Is XML data in a config file a string? That may be its datatype when you read the file, but would you try to manipulate it with string functions and regexes? No. You parse it into a data structure with an XML parser. Likewise SQL is a string with *programmatic meaning*, if you're manipulating it as a string you're doing it wrong. A query builder with a fluent interface is a good alternative: `queryBuilder.select(['title', 'isbn']).from('books').where('author').is('Salman Rushdie');`

Comment: @JaredSmith:Isn't it too much for such a simple case?

Comment: **No**. First, its a bad habit. Second, it cuts against the grain of the language: in case the 8 million calls to `.append` didn't tip you off, the OO version is much more natural in Java. Third, SQL via string concatenation is notoriously prone to SQL injection security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Lastly, with the OO version you can validate the construction piecemeal, with the string version if you mess it up, you'll just get an incomprehensible db error.

Comment: As multiple comments and both answers (so far) have pointed out, _never put your parameters in the query_. That is setting yourself up for a SQL injection attack. **Always use SQL parameters with a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`**. It is more work, but infinitely more secure (your current way has zero security).

Comment: No need to use stringbuilder in this case. The compiler will make the optimisation anyway http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Comment: **No again!** This is an extraordinary bad idea. You might gain some nanoseconds by creating the query faster and you will (probably) lose milliseconds more when the query gets executed. Then you change `customerId` to `customerEmail` and my email is `bye bye'; DROP DATABASE` or like (the exact exploit depends on your escaping method). There are many DB-related optimizations out there, but none of them really cares about fast string concatenation. That's orders of magnitude off.

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion is:

```
public class SQLHandler {  

    private String sql=
    "SELECT \n"+
    "   c.customer_representative_id, \n"+
    "   c.first_name \n"+
    "FROM \n"+
    "   customer_table c JOIN representative_table r ON \n"+
    "   r.customer_representative_id=c.id \n"+
    "WHERE \n"+
    "   customer_table.id=? \n";
 
    // methods and so on...

}
```

The `"\n"` characters at the end of every line makes for a nice printing for debugging purposes.

Then, use a `PreparedStatement` to substitute "?" thus preventing SQL injection:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(customed_id);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
/// etc...
```

---

**Another alternative is reading the SQL String from a file** that can be done with the `Properties` class. Such file can have multiple properties, each one being a different SQL query or other kind of configuration values you want.

Sample file (the `" \"` is to allow multi-line values for properties. It is indeed interpreted as a single line)

```
SQL1=\
SELECT \
    c.customer_representative_id, \
    c.first_name \
FROM \
    customer_table c JOIN representative_table r ON \
    r.customer_representative_id=c.id \
WHERE \
    customer_table.id=? \
```

Which can be loaded like this:

```
import java.util.Properties;
///...
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("sql_queries.conf"));
String sql = prop.getProperty("SQL1");
```

Then uses a `PreparedStatement` ...

**Bonus suggestion:**

Create views with the joins that you'll be doing frequently, so the queries look simpler in the code or in the property file, like:

```java
SELECT
    v.customer_representative_id,
    v.first_name,
        //other columns
FROM
    my_reps_view v
WHERE
    v.customer_table.id=?
```

Comment: I usually use this approach, but typically I leave the selected columns in a string constant that is separated by commas. The columns may change (you may need to add few during the lifetime of the program), but the table names usually don't change, and the join columns are also set in stone usually. If you join multiple tables, do a static columns(String) function returning String that substitutes the "c." part into the return value. The rationale is that you may need many queries that select the same set of columns, because they return the same types of objects.

Comment: +1.  Note that this is *no less efficient* than using a StringBuilder, because the compiler converts it to code that uses a StringBuilder in pretty much exactly the same way as OP's code.

Comment: @Jules Consecutive String constants (literals and final Strings of literals) are concatenated at compile time. If the entire String is constant, no StringBuilder is instantiated. While you are correct that the above example is _no less efficient_, it _can be_ more efficient to use concatenation in this particular case. In practice, the difference is likely negligible.

Comment: My personal preference is to store queries in external .sql files and load them via Class#getResourceAsStream(). This is especially helpful if your editor supports syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

## Raw String Literals

Work is underway to introduce [raw string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings) literals into the Java language. Along with that comes the [multi-line strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Multiline_string_literals) desired in this Question.

### JEP 326

See [*JEP 326: Raw String Literals*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326).

Excerpts:

> Add raw string literals to the Java programming language. A raw string literal can span multiple lines of source code and does not interpret escape sequences, such as \n, or Unicode escapes, of the form \uXXXX …
>
> supply strings targeted for grammars other than Java, …
>
> supply strings that span several lines of source without supplying special indicators for new lines.

Nesting SQL is one of the example use-cases given in the JEP.

### Status update by Brian Goetz

See [*Raw string literals -- where we are, how we got here*](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2018-March/000446.html) by Brian Goetz, 2018-03-27.

They are leaning towards using any number of [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming) as the raw-string-literal starting-stopping [delimiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter). A single backtick would be most common, but use a number of them if the text value happens to contain backticks. So no [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) needed at all.

Excerpts:

> … things have largely stabilized with raw string literals …
>
> ```
>     String ss = `a multi-
>      line-string`;
> ```

---

By the way, you may find the article, [*New Methods on Java Strings With JDK 11*](https://dzone.com/articles/new-methods-on-java-strings-with-jdk-11) by Dustin Marx to be interesting. It covers some new Unicode-savvy string-trimming methods being added to Java 11. These may be related to the eventual raw string literals feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the overhead of a "fluent"-style Java query builder (like jOOQ or something), I've used static strings for queries formatted like so:

```
public class SQLHandler {
    private static final String REPRESENTATIVES_QUERY =
        " SELECT" +
        "   representative_table.id," +
        "   representative_table.first_name," +
        " FROM" +
        "   customer_table" +
        " JOIN representative_table ON" +
        "   representative_table.id = customer_table.id" +
        " WHERE" +
        "   customer_table.id = ?";

    public static ArrayList<Representatives> getRepresentatives(int customerId) {
        // do query
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completness you could add an extra step to compilation to make it possible to inject the value from the javadoc comment like by using [multiline-string project](https://github.com/adrianwalker/multiline-string) and have something like:

```
/**
 * SELECT 'Hello world'
 * FROM dual
 */
@Multiline
public static String getHelloWorld;
```

It will replace the annotation at compile time with

```
public static String getHelloWorld= "SELECT 'Hello world'\nFROM dual";
```

And just in case that you have some concerns I've used it with a JPA entity manager like

```
javax.persistence.Query qry = em.createQuery(QueryRepository.getHelloWorld);
```

where `QueryRepository` is a conventional [class for constants](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=2).

Tutorial on development and usage: http://www.adrianwalker.org/2011/12/java-multiline-string.html

Answer (score 0):

For large complicated queries I usually use a string template. This way, when I want to change the query, it's just a big `.sql` file that I can edit with syntax highlighting to boot. There's a lot of different string template libraries around I'll leave it generalized.

It's definitely slower to process the template than it is to concatenate a bunch of strings, but sometimes it's worth it to me for the ease of maintenance.

**String Template**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.this = table2.that
WHERE table1.foo = ?
AND table2.baz = ?
```

**Java**

```
StringTemplate template = new MyQueryTemplate().
String query = template.process();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1, "bar");
statement.setString(2, "boo");
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Multiple-line-syntax](https://github.com/11039850/monalisa-orm/wiki/Multiple-line-syntax)

It also support variables in multiline string, for example:

```
String name="zzg";
String lines = ""/**~!{
    SELECT * 
        FROM user
    WHERE name="$name"
}*/;
System.out.println(lines);
```

Output：

```
SELECT * 
    FROM user
    WHERE name="zzg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about everyone trying to help you build strings. What you are doing is voluntarily creating a HUGE sql injection target. Hackers will love you. You are giving them everything they need to break into your database, extract your data, or change your data.